# Trying to write test results to a report file under specific test areas

Tags: python, arrays, text, resultset, txt

**I'm trying to create a report where each test is recorded under it's respective criteria. The first test seems to work and is recorded under criteria 1 in the text file. The next test should write under criteria 2 in the text file but doesn't. Anyone have any ideas?

This is what the report.txt looks like currently with the first results. The rest I need under their respective number/test.

## ================================================================================================================================
A3D Single Install

---

1 Did the installation complete successfully
Installation: Successful.

7513 Successes
0 Warnings
0 Non Fatal Errors
0 Fatal Errors

---

### 2 Installed shortcuts. *.ico files should get installed in bin folder to be used by registry entries and IQR/IQJ images

3 Installed files/folders match those of the central area

---

4 Was the license file correctly copied and updated (temp lic when only the viewer is installed (lic panel should not be displayed))

---

5 Were correct CIQEL files in correct location (updated correctly)

---

6 Were the correct cadscript/bin/plat-XXX/cadscript_XXX installed (no extras)

---

7 Was cadiq or cadiq.bat updated correctly

---

8 Were the correct version_xx.txt and cadscript.cfg files in their correct place

---

9 Was cadscript.cfg updated correctly

---

10 Was the correct pdelib files there

---

11 Does a CADIQ Analysis work

---

12 Overall Pass/Fail**

```
def writeReport(cadsys, drive, version, ): #writes content to report file without truncating
   reportFile = 'report.txt'
   bigspacer = '================================================================================================================================'
   littlespacer = '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
   si = ' Single Install'
   criteria = ['0',
      '1 Did the installation complete successfully',
      '2 Installed shortcuts. *.ico files should get installed in bin folder to be used by registry entries and IQR/IQJ images %CADIQ_HOME%\\samples\\cadiq\\compare_*\\*.iqr',
      '3 Installed files/folders match those of the central area',
      '4 Was the license file correctly copied and updated (temp lic when only the viewer is installed (lic panel should not be displayed))',
      '5 Were correct CIQEL files in correct location (updated correctly)',
      '6 Were the correct cadscript/bin/plat-XXX/cadscript_XXX installed (no extras)',
      '7 Was cadiq or cadiq.bat updated correctly',
      '8 Were the correct version_xx.txt and cadscript.cfg files in their correct place',
      '9 Was cadscript.cfg updated correctly',
      '10 Was the correct pdelib files there',
      '11 Does a CADIQ Analysis work',
      '12 Overall Pass/Fail']
   installpath = drive + ':\\CADIQ\\v' + version + '_' + cadsys + '_si'
   passes = 0
   fails = 0
   NAs = 0

   content = bigspacer + '\n' + cadsys + si + '\n' + bigspacer + '\n'
```

Now there is a loop for each of the test criterias

```
for test in criteria:
  if test == criteria[0]:
     continue

  content += '\n' + littlespacer + '\n' + test + '\n'
  testsuccess = 1
  nonapplicable = 0
  relevantfolder = None
```

Here is an example of the first test which seems to work but I think only because it's the first test so appends to the correct location, the first spot. I need it to move on to the next test and append it to the correct location in the text file.

```
if test == criteria[1]:
     for file in os.listdir(installpath + '\\Logs'):
        if file.startswith('CADIQ_Win_v' + version + '_Install'):
           relevantfolder = installpath + '\\Logs\\' + file
           break
     if relevantfolder == None:
        testsuccess = 0
        content += 'DID NOT FIND INSTALL LOG ' + installpath + '\\Logs\n'
     else:
        content += relevantfolder + '\n'
        copyindex = 0
        with open(installpath + '\\Logs\\' + file) as f:
           for line in f:
              if line.startswith('Installation:'):
                 copyindex = 6
                 if line.find('Successful') < 0:
                    testsuccess = 0
              if copyindex:
                 content += line
                 copyindex -= 1
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: What does `doesn't work` mean? Does it give an error? Does it replace the old text? Does it not append?

Comment: @Cagri As I said, the first test results are appended but the second test is not.